# Проверка файла, загруженного из формы методом post

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

возникла непонятная ситуация при отправке файлов методом post и отправке их в БД.
Собственно, когда отправляю пустое поле. Читает как будто файл не пустой и его значение NULL, так же и выводит в БД.

```
if (!empty($_FILES['docs']['name']) && ($_FILES['docs']['size'])>0) {
    $doc = $_FILES['docs']['name'];
    $docs = $_FILES['docs'];

    foreach ($docs['tmp_name'] as $index => $Path) {
        if (!array_key_exists($index, $docs['name'])) {
            continue;
        }
        move_uploaded_file($Path, __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$docs['name'][$index]);
    }
 if (filesize($doc[0])>0) {
 $text_file = file_get_contents($doc[0]);
 $text2 = $text_file;
 // Операции с текстом внутри файла
$a2 = count($arr2);
 $pdo -> query($selectQuery2)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $insertQuery3 = "INSERT INTO uploaded_text (content, date, words_count) VALUES('$text_file',NOW(),'$a2')";
 $pdo -> exec($insertQuery3) or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));
 $text_id2 = $pdo->lastInsertId();
 foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $slovo2) {
     $slovo2 = trim($slovo2);
 if ($slovo2 == false or $slovo2 == "") {
     unset($arr2[$key2]);
 } 
 }
 $count2 = array_count_values($arr2);
 foreach ($count2 as $word2 => $count_2) {
    $insertQuery4 = "INSERT INTO word (text_id,word,count) VALUES('$text_id2','$word2','$count_2')";
    $pdo -> exec($insertQuery4) or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo(), true));
}
}
}[![фото с БД][1]][1]
```

Comment: Фото с БД не приложилось, но там в значении контекст стоит NULL, а количество символов файла = 1. Что значит NULL, записан как символ или что то вроде того

Comment: Ребят, нашел решение проблемы. В офф. документации говориться .... 

В случае, если при отправке формы файл выбран не был, PHP установит переменную $_FILES['userfile']['size'] значением 0, а переменную $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] - none.

По окончанию работы скрипта, если загруженный файл не был переименован или перемещен, он будет автоматически удален из временной папки.
А так как в цикле по движу подгруженных файлов у меня не было проверки на пустоту временного имени tmp_name, я её добавил. И если временное имя файла пустое, он файл не двигает и значения файла не изменяется на NULL